# wordpress media_handle_upload to work with blob or base64

Tags: posts

case : i am trying to upload webrecord audio to wordress post . so i have form with post id and input type file "audio_upload"

below is my code snippet

```
 $audio_meta_value = media_handle_upload( 'audio_upload', $pid);
```

above code works fine.

Issue:
i have added webrecord to my form at bottom , i am able to save audio via below code using ajax , but i am stuck with adding that audio to my post that .

Any possible solution ?
1: Is there any wordpress function that accepts **blob data / base64 encode** instead of $_FILES to save attachment.

2: can i do append blob data to file input in form so my previous flow will works

**code to save audio via ajax**

```
Fr.voice.export(function(blob){
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', blob);

  $.ajax({
    url: "server.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      // Sent to Server
    }
  });
}, "blob");
```

Upload.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
  // $audio = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
  $audio = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $newpath = "soundrec/uploaded_audio".time().".wav";
  rename($audio,$newpath);
  echo $newpath;
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I'm running into a similar issue trying to get `media_handle_upload()` working with a blob type.

Comment: I'm also having issues with this - grateful any help!

Answer (score 2):

you can do that with the function `wp_handle_sideload`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_handle_sideload/

Steps to make this :

1. create a temporary file with the content you need
2. pass this filename to function `wp_handle_sideload`